# Prove that $ x^xy^y=z^z $ has infinite integral solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show that there exist an infinite number of solutions for $$ x^xy^y=z^z $$ where $x,y,z \gt 1$ & $x,y,z\in \mathbb Z$

I don't know how to even start,infact I am not able to find a particular solution of this problem let alone infinite.How to approach?

Comment: maybe it can be shown by first rewriting the expression by redefining $x^x$, $y^y$ and $z^z$ as $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ resulting in $XY=Z$ which defines a surface in the three dimensional space. can this be a useful point start from?

Comment: If $v_p(n)$ denotes the highest power $k$ such that $p^k\mid n$, then the equation $x^xy^y=z^z$ is equivalent to
$$v_p(x)x+v_p(y)y=v_p(z)z\;\;\text{ for all primes }p$$
Thus for example, if it were the case that $x=2^a$, $y=2^b$, $z=2^c$, then we would have to have
$$a2^a+b2^b=c2^c$$

Comment: OP, what is the source of this interesting question?

Comment: (just a half-formed thought above, wanted to write it down in case anyone saw something in it)

Comment: @vadim123 http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/Maths/Courseware/NumberTheory/Exercises-01.pdf

Comment: Apparently the exercise appears at the end of the first chapter: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/Maths/Courseware/NumberTheory/NumberTheory.pdf (page 1-11) so it has an elementary solution.

Comment: The unpublished manuscript source is quite rough in places, and should not be considered an authority.  This problem may be incorrect, or may not have an elementary solution.  Perhaps five stars means "open problem".

Comment: It seems this question has already been asked.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497702/do-there-exist-an-infinite-number-of-integer-solutions-x-y-z-of-xx-cdot-y?rq=1